# Running exactly x number of commands

Tags: python, shell

I have a total of n commands to be run from Shell Script, out of which x should be running at any given time. Till now I have:

```
command 1 &
command 2 &
..
..
command x &
wait
```

Although the above code makes sure that no more than x commands are running at a time, it will keep waiting until the first x commands are finished to spawn the next x. I would like the next one command to be executed as soon as the any one of these x is finished. How can I achieve that?

On a side note, can this be achieved by writing a script in Python as well?

Comment: are there any pattern in these commands ?

Comment: Is it a single command with varying parameters or multiple commands? You could do it in python with a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` with a worker that uses `subprocess.check_call` to run the commands.

Comment: @iamauser : Yes, these are basically the same command with different parameters.

Comment: @tdelaney: I want to run them as different processes as they are scrapy commands (which do not support multithreading). Is threadpool the right way to go?

Comment: Pool (multiprocessing) or ThreadPool (multithreading) will work. Threading is fine because the worker uses `subprocess.check_call` to run scrapy as a child process - most of the time its just sitting there waiting for scrapy to finish. Use pool.map() with `chunksize=1` so that the threads are always fetching new commands to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Now that you have provided some more info about your actual needs, I would suggest you the names of all the sites that you wish to crawl in a failed called `sites.txt`, one per line, like this:

```
www.google.com
www.hp.com
www.ibm.com
```

Then you can run `GNU Parallel` like this:

```
parallel -j n -a sites.txt scrapy crawl
```

If you want to direct the output to separate file for each command, you can use syntax like this if your command supports the `-o <outputfile>` option:

```
parallel -j n -a sites.txt scrape crawl {} -o {}.json
```

and `parallel` will substitute the sitename where it sees `{}`, so that will produce output files

```
www.google.com.json
```

and so on.

**Original Answer**

Use `GNU Parallel`. In general, if you want `n` jobs running, use

```
parallel -j n command
```

Without knowing how to generate your parameters it is hard to advise further, except that parameters can come from a file if you use `-a file` or, if they are essentially filenames, you can put them afterwards separated by triple colons

```
parallel -j n command ::: *.jpg
```

Comment: To be more specific, I am running a the command `scrapy crawl <spidername>` where <spidername> will keep on changing between the commands.

Comment: So put all the <spidernames> in a file called `sites.txt`, one per line, and use `parallel -j n -a sites.txt crawl`

Comment: That was great help. Thanks a lot!
Is there a way to also redirect the output of these spiders to individual files?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using xargs -P$x.  I regularly use xargs for keeping all cores on a given system running or for making sure my cpu's are saturated during time critical applications

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the use of xargs. I am unable to see the full picture.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*foo.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -P$x -iFOO command FOO

Comment: The xargs command can accept a list... It is not limited to the output of **find**.